# How do you modify an Msvm_VirtualSystemGlobalSettingData class in C#?

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I'm trying to modify the AutomaticStartupAction (and shutdown) value in a given VM. I've got some code written for it, but the job always fails. I can show the sample code, but I'd like to know in general how to modify these properties in a VM, please.

I've been able to get the right class and the current value of AutomaticStartupAction, but I'm unable to modify it using ModifyVirtualSystem (as the Microsoft docs suggest). I think I'm doing it correctly, but apparently there's something I don't know. When the call to ModifyVirtualSystem is made, it launches a job, but the job always fails, so I know I'm passing good data. I've got a lot of functions modifying VMs through WMI, there's just something about associators I apparently don't understand or maybe I'm solving the wrong problem.

So what's the C# code for modifying the AutomaticStartupAction value via the WMI provider?

Comment: The credentials which runs the query must have privileges. in some wmi classes even administrator doesn't have full access! try system32\wbem\wbemtester.exe, or running you application on another computer, or writing a windows service with local system account. it seems that local system has the highest privilege level.

Comment: By the way you can set the permissions in these 3 places(but it doesn't always work):

1.Start->Run->dcmoncnfg->Component Services->Computers->My Computer->Properties->COM security 
2.Start->Run->dcmoncnfg->Component Services->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config->Windows Management and Instrumention->Properties->Security
3.Start->Run->wmimgmt.msc->WMI Control(Local)->Properties->Root(just highlight)->Security

Comment: It does actually run as a windows service with local system. No luck.

Comment: Its not quite related, but a while back I was working on trying to automatically revert to a snapshot if certain events occurred, which also uses the ModifyVirtualSystem function. I was trying to do it in Python, using a WMI Library, and I just could not get it to work, running into issues with the associators too. I ended up just using Powershell scripts to do that part of the process, and then called that from Python.

Comment: Unfortunately powershell isn't an option here. It needs to be through the WMI provider.

Comment: Still no resolution on this issue. Hoping it's easier to change in 2012